# String parameter in a SQL query in Javascript

Tags: sql

I am executing this SQL query

```
SELECT 
    Export_3040.[160010] 
FROM Export_3040 
WHERE (Export_3040.[160010] = ('K3'))
```

I want to parametrize 'K3'

```
AConnection.Open();  
Cmd = ADO.CreateCommand();
Cmd.ActiveConnection = AConnection;
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText;
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Export_3040.[160010] FROM Export_3040 WHERE (Export_3040.[160010] = MyParam)";
Prm = Cmd.CreateParameter("MyParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100);
Cmd.Parameters.Append(Prm);
Prm.Value = "K3";
RecSet = Cmd.Execute();
```

on the last line, I get this error: `'MyParam' not recognized as a valid field name or expression...`
I tested with an integer parameter (AdInteger type) and it works but when I try with the string parameter, I get the error...
It might be the size of the string parameter but I couldn't find a way to make it work...

Comment: Probably should be @MyParam

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if you really meant to tag this javascript, but mate, this is plain text why not just do it this way:

```
AConnection.Open();  
Cmd = ADO.CreateCommand();
Cmd.ActiveConnection = AConnection;
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText;
var myParam= "K3";
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Export_3040.[160010] FROM Export_3040 WHERE (Export_3040.[160010] ="+myParam+")";
RecSet = Cmd.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AConnection.Open();  
Cmd = ADO.CreateCommand();
Cmd.ActiveConnection = AConnection;
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText;
Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Export_3040.[160010] FROM Export_3040 WHERE (Export_3040.[160010] = 
@MyParam)";
Cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyParam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "K3"; 
RecSet = Cmd.Execute();
```

Comment: Possibly you could just try and let the command object infer the type size info: Cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyParam", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "K3"; (Then Leave the .value and .append out).  Remember to Keep the commandtext to include the parameter in.

Comment: Sorry, can't quite understand this

Answer (score 0):

OK so this is the code that worked for me, thanks everyone!

```
Cmd.ActiveConnection = AConnection;  
myParam = "K3"  
Cmd.CommandType = adCmdText;  
Cmd.CommandText = aqString.Format("SELECT Export_3040.[160010] FROM Export_3040 WHERE Export_3040.[160010] = " + "\'" + "%s" + "\'",    myParam);  
RecSet = Cmd.Execute();
```